# Problems with port map in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fpga

i'm making a bo/bc college assignment in vhdl using modelsim, and inside my operational block i need to port map some of my components (register,adder and comparator)but when i compile all the files together, all the three components compile correctly but the bo dont, the compiler tell's me that for all the three components: " Identifier "registrador" does not identify a component declaration." for example.
heres my bo code:

https://goo.gl/oNFnd8

thanks for any help!

Comment: Please include a minimal and complete example as source code in your question.

Comment: sorry, i didnt know how to do that either :P

Comment: Copy the source code into the question text and ident all lines by 4 spaces. Source code needs at least 1 empty line  to separate it from normal text.

Comment: i'll remember that next time! thanks for the advise.

Comment: Your profile shows you haven't taken the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), which explains how to interact successfully with Stack Overflow. Also see the Help Center, [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't declared your components, you are presumably trying to use direct entity instantiation. The syntax for this is not:

```
reg : registrador port map (...);
```

Instead, it is:

```
reg : entity work.registrador port map (...);
```

(assuming you have already compiled "registrador" into library work. If you compiled it into another library, substitute that library's name).

Comment: Thanks very much! that solved my problem. i'm just learning VHDL so i didnt know exactly what i was doing , thanks again for the help! :D

Comment: @FelipeChabatura you would typically mark this answer as correct if it solved your problem